# form submitting even after return false jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

my simple jquery code is showing the alter box but also submiting the form. why its happening ? when enter key is pressed and if length is less than 3 then it should show error and should not submit the form, but it is submitting the form even after showing the error.

```
            $('#frmSearch input').keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                if ($('#frmSearch input').val().length < 3) {
                    alert("SEARCH TEXT TOO SHORT");
                    return (false);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#frmSearch').submit();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Need more information. What string are you testing with? Nothing is wrong with the code you posted here, assuming your selectors are correct.

Comment: Why the () around false?

Comment: Thought that was weird too-- but syntactically it should work the same. I'm thinking this is probably browser taking over form submit. Need more info.

Comment: You need paste your HTML so we can help you diagnose.

Comment: Also if you remove else part your code doesn't work because when you push enter the form will be automatically submit. You need to prevent this.

Answer (score 2):

Enter key automatically submits the form. You can do it like this:

```
$("#frmSearch").submit(function(e){
   if ($('#frmSearch input').val().length < 3) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("SEARCH TEXT TOO SHORT");
   }
}
```

and you are not handling submit event but keydown event which doesn't stop submit from calling.

Answer (score 1):

you can try so also, use the **keypress** not use **keydown**

```
(function ($) {
  $ ('# frmSearch input'). keypress (function (e) {
             if (e.KeyCode == 13) {
                 if ($ ('# frmSearch input'). val (). length <3) {
                     alert ("SEARCH TEXT TOO SHORT");
                     return (false);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     $ ('# frmSearch') submit ().;
                 }
             }
         });

}) (jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes an Enter key can automatically submit a form by default.  If you want to intercept and prevent that behavior, you can stop the default submit.
I would put `e.preventDefault()` in your code.

***Updated***

```
$('#frmSearch input').keydown(function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        //Prevents default submit
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($('#frmSearch input').val().length < 3) {
            alert("SEARCH TEXT TOO SHORT");
            return (false);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#frmSearch').submit();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You'd still have to check which key was pressed before using preventDefault. Otherwise you can't type anything in the input box if you do it for every key.

Comment: Antonio - OK, if that's the case, then I updated the location of e.preventDefault to after checking for keyCode 13.  I don't know what other keys would have default functionality though.

Comment: Just try it for yourself and you will quickly understand what I mean.